# Akka and built in Scala Actors: What's the difference for local use?

Tags: scala, actor, akka

I know that [Akka](http://akka.io) is a powerful ([actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model)) framework capable of concurrently running tasks on distributed systems. I know that there's [a great comparison](http://doc.akka.io/docs/misc/Comparison_between_4_actor_frameworks.pdf) of actor model implementations in [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/). But I'm still wondering whether there are any benefits of using Akka for local calculations on multicore machine over built in Scala actors? And which one of them is more effective in terms of memory/CPU usage?

Comment: Scala Actors is pulled out into its own jar for Scala 2.10 and will be deprecated as well. Akka will be shipped as the successor. As for efficiency Akka has a pretty solid story. Feel free to benchmark yourself.

Comment: @ViktorKlang It would be accepted answer if it were not a comment. Deprecation is a solid reason for not using built in Scala actors. +1 and thanks :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Scala Actors is pulled out into its own jar for Scala 2.10 and will be deprecated as well. Akka will be shipped as the successor. As for efficiency Akka has a pretty solid story. Feel free to benchmark yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Builtin Scala Actors are deprecated from Scala 2.10 , default library is Akka.See [Scala 2.10 release announcement](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/27499)

Here is the [Migration Guide to Akka](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/actors-migration-guide.html).